# HTML Table not forming in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to concanetate the strings to form a proper html table in ajax. 
tr and td forming ok but problem with table.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: hosturl,
            success: function (e)
            {
               $("#t1").append("<table>");
               $("#t1").append("<tr> <th> Book Name </th> <th> Publisher Name </th> <th> Publish Year </th> </tr>");

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                { 

                    $("#t1").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + e[j].bookName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publisherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                }
                $("#t1").append("<table>");
            },
  <div> Book DETAILS :</div> <br>
  <div id="t1">  </div>
```

Comment: var str = "<table>" str+= "<tr>" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append a partial element to the dom, i.e. the start of a table then later the end of it.
A simple solution to your problem is to just build the HTML table string first then append it.

```
        success: function (e)
        {
           var table = "<table>";
           table += "<tr> <th> Book Name </th> <th> Publisher Name </th> <th> Publish Year </th> </tr>";

            for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            { 

                table += "<tr>" + "<td>" + e[j].bookName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publisherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>";
            }
            table += "</table>";
            $("#t1").append(table);
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

First,you can append a `table` to `t1` element,then you can append `tr` to the table directly.

So in your `success` event function,change to below:

```
$("#t1").append("<table><tr> <th> Book Name </th> <th> Publisher Name </th> <th> Publish Year </th> </tr></table>"); 
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{ 
    $("#t1>table").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + e[j].bookName + "</td>" 
         + "<td>" + e[j].publisherName + "</td>" 
         + "<td>" + e[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>");
}
```